# run icacls across domains - failed trust relationship

Tags: active-directory, powershell, samba, file-permissions

I frequently have to create Directories and set permissions on Samba-Shares which are joined to foreign Domains without Trust Relationship to my "home" Domain.

Mounting and creating Directories works fine

```
New-PSDrive -Name "F" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $someNAS -Persist -Credential $admin_in_foreign_domain

New-Item -Path "F:\a\b\testdir" -ItemType Directory
```

but changing Permissions on that newly created Folder fails.

```
icacls.exe "F:\a\b\testdir" /inheritance:r /grant "$($foreign_domain)\$($some_username):(OI)(CI)(RX,W)"
```

results in

```
domain\User The Trust Relationship Between This Workstation and the Primary Domain Failed
```

using Powershell Get/Set-ACL didn´t even work within our own Domain. This is probably a Samba issue (didn´t test further).

Any idea how to get around this without using domain-joined computers?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you don't have a trust, you will need to grant permissions to the *SID* for the security principal in question. I.e., the domain SID of ForeignDomain\Username.

Comment: Or perhaps you need to run `icacls.exe` with [runas](https://ss64.com/nt/runas.html), specify the external domain credential which you can talk with its domain controller, and see if the command works. Something like this for example may do it.... `RUNAS /user:<foreign domain>\<username> icacls.exe "F:\a\b\testdir" /inheritance:r /grant "$($foreign_domain)\$($some_username):(OI)(CI)(RX,W)"`